# cannot turn on hp mini 210

Tags: power

I trying to switch on my hp mini 210 laptop and nothing appear on the screen(black screen). I also cannot see the bios setup as usual. So what action should i take to make my laptop work again?

Answer (score 0):

If the battery can be removed, try removing it, disconnect from AC adapter too, and leave it there for 30 seconds. After doing that, connect it to the AC adapter only and turn it on.

If it works, shutdown, connect the battery back and try to turn it on again. If it works, lucky you, your battery is not bricked. Otherwise you will have to get a new one, or use the equipment with AC adapter only.

Edit:

Have you checked for stuck keyboard keys? Tab all keys and see if it turn on after.

If it doesn't help, check if there is any memory in the memory slot under your laptop (you may have to remove some screws to access that). Remove the memory and try to start the laptop.

If it works, shutdown, clean the memory contacts with a soft eraser (do **not** use an abrasive eraser), put it back and try again. It should work, if not, this memory is damaged and have to be replaced.

I'm listing just the common issues, but assuming your laptop is turning on but not initializing, it can be literally any defect, ranging from a stuck button to motherboard damage. If the usual checks don't help, perhaps you should hand this to a professional. Laptops are full of compact and fragile parts, and messing around without skill can easily turn this into a bigger problem.

Comment: I already done your suggestion but it could not work.

Answer (score 0):

Plug a regular monitor into the VGA output to see if the onboard video chip is bad. If you get video on external monitor then your internal video is ok and you either have a disconnected cable most likely on the back of the LCD panel itself.

It's under a little flap of tape – pull out and reseat it. If that does not work then it is either the backlight in LCD, the backlight inverter, or the LCD panel itself. On a laptop that small all parts may be fused as one part.

Can you see a dark picture if you look at it from and angle with some help from different lights and angles maybe a flashlight? If you can see a dark picture it's between the backlight or the inverter. No picture: Buy a new LCD.

My HP Mini 110 cable was slightly off: Behind the LCD panel I was getting blue lines. After reseating the cable it works perfect. Maybe you have the same problem.